# Searching for a term, foreign derivation but used in English

Tags: single-word-requests

There's a word of foreign derivation but used in English for a position within an organization created to provide someone favored by that organization a paid position with no real duties. Is anyone familiar with this word? I can't remember it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe **sinecure** is the word you are looking for:

> **sinecure**
>   NOUN
>
> A position requiring little or no work but giving the holder status or financial benefit.
>   ‘*political sinecures for the supporters of ministers*’
>
> Origin
>   Mid 17th century: from Latin sine cura ‘without care’.
>
> [*Oxford Living Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sinecure)